# Conditional manipulation on the text element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a d3 visualization that has a variety of classes of text and a search box.  I want one class of the text ("second") to initially have a `font-size` of `0`.  If there is a match with the content of the search box, I want the `font-size` of "second" to become `12`.

I tried to do this initially by putting a rectangle over the "second" text, and having the rectangle turn a solid white to cover the text if it is not a match.

```
d3.select("#txtName").on("keydown", function() {
  var txtName = d3.select("#txtName").node().value;
  var meow = function(frat) {
    return frat.includes(txtName.toLowerCase());
  }
  rect.style("opacity", function(d) {
    return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "1" : "0";  
  })
```

But it would be much better if the text collapsed in size, leaving only the text classes `label1` and `first` showing because my users are complaining of information overload (my original dataset has a lot of information and with all text classes on the screen, it's pretty overwhelming).  D3 doesn't seem able to select the text for conditional formatting in the same way that it can select the rectangles however.

Here's what I tried:

```
svgs2.style("font-size", function(d) {
  return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "12" : "0";  
})
```

> (error code: typeError: frat is undefined.)

```
svgs2.selectAll("text").style("font-size", function(d) {
  return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "12" : "0";  
})
```

> (two error codes: `typeError: frat is undefined`. and `undefined has
>   no properties.`)

```js
var doc = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`TooltipInfo Category Function1 Function2 Retention
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate Design Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Jack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Drooling Jack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Drooling Jack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum ADVERTISING At home Jack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum PROMOTIONS At home Jack 100
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Publications At homeio Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Public and Information Services At homeio Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Snack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Fundraising Optimal time of day Snack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Protective Measures Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Protective Measures Pack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8`]));

d3.tsv(doc)
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      University: d.University,
      TooltipInfo: d.TooltipInfo,
      Category: d.Category,
      Function1: d.Function1,
      Function2: d.Function2,
      MaxRetentionRounded: d.MaxRetentionRounded,
      ModifiedRetention: d.ModifiedRetention
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, data) {


      //         var allGroup = d3.map(data, function(d){return(d.Function1)}).keys()
      // console.log(allGroup)

      // console.log(allGroup.length);
      var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0)

      var height = 150,
        width = 300;



      var nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Function2;
        })
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Function1;
        })
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Category;
        })
        .entries(data);

      // var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      //  .attr("class", "tooltip")
      //  .style("opacity", 0)



      var height = 80,
        width = 150;


      var divs = d3.select(".container")
        .selectAll(null)
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "innerdiv");

      divs.append("p")
        .html(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        });



      var divs2 = divs.selectAll(null)
        .data(function(d) {
          return d.values;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr("class", "first")


      divs2.append("text")
        .attr('class', 'label1')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("width", 400)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

      var svgs2 = divs2.selectAll(null)
        .data(function(d) {
          return d.values;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('svg')
        .attr("class", "second")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return String(d.Category).length * 31
        })
        // .attr("width",200)
        .attr("height", 20);


      svgs2.append("text")
        .attr('class', 'label2')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 17)
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')


      var rect = svgs2.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .filter(function(d, i) {
          const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
          return x.key == d.Category ? 1 : 0;
        })
        // .attr("transform", function(d, i) {return "translate(" + String(d.Category).length*7.3 + ",0)";})
        .attr("width", function(d, i) {
          return String(d.Category).length * 7.3
        })
        .attr("x", 5)
        .attr("y", 8)
        .attr("height", 20)

        // .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (height-40)-(d.MaxRetentionRounded*5);})
        .attr("fill", "transparent")
        // .style("opacity","0")
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
          div.html(`${d.TooltipInfo}`)
            .style("left", function() {
              return d3.event.pageX > (window.innerWidth * .75) ? d3.event.pageX - 520 + "px" : d3.event.pageX + "px"
            })
            .style("bottom", function() {
              var clientrect = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect();
              return d3.event.pageY > (window.innerHeight - clientrect.height) ? window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY + "px" : window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY - clientrect.height + "px"
            })
          // .style(function() {return "bottom"}, window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY+20 +"px")
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        });

      // var rect2 = svgs2.selectAll("line")
      // .data(data)
      // .enter().append("line")
      // .attr("class", "bar")
      // .filter(function(d, i) {
      //  const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
      //  return x.key == d.Category ? 1 : 0;
      // })
      // .attr("x1", "0")
      // .attr("x2", function(d, i) {return String(d.Category).length*7.3})
      // .attr("y1", "10")
      // .attr("y2", "10")
      // // .attr("x2", "12")
      //
      // // .attr("transform", function(d, i) {return "translate(" + String(d.Category).length*7.3 + ",0)";})
      // .attr("stroke-width", 15)
      // .style("stroke","black")
      // .style("stroke-opacity",0)
      // .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      //  return (i * 20)+10;
      // })
      //
      //
      // // .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (height-40)-(d.MaxRetentionRounded*5);})
      // .attr("fill", "blue")
      // .style("opacity","1");



      var hat = function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
          //code to execute here
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      };

      d3.select("#txtName").on("keydown", function() {
        var txtName = d3.select("#txtName").node().value;
        var meow = function(frat) {
          return frat.includes(txtName.toLowerCase());
        }
        //rect.style("fill", function(d) {
          //return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "yellow" : "transparent";
      //  })
        //rect.style("stroke", function(d) {
          //return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "black" : "transparent";
       // })
        rect.style("opacity", function(d) {
          return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "1" : "0";
        })
        divs2.selectAll("text").style("color", function(d) {
          return txtName.length > 1 ? "lightgray" : "black";
        })
        //svgs2.selectAll("text").style("font-size", function(d) {
          //return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "12" : "0";
        //})

      }) })
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 17px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: black;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.innerdiv {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
  flex: 1 1 1;
}

.innerdiv+.innerdiv {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
}

.legend {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}


/* div {width: auto; height: auto; } */

.first>*:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

div.first {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

 <textarea id="txtName" name="txt-Name" style="width:600px; height:20px;" ></textarea>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Is there a way to manipulate the `font-size` of the text?

UPDATE: I finally figured out how to select the text element without using `d3.selectAll`: `svgs2.style("fill", "blue")`.  In other words, the following code will turn the text blue once the keyup event has been triggered:

```js
d3.select("#txtName").on("keydown", function() {
      var txtName = d3.select("#txtName").node().value;
      var meow = function(frat) {
        return frat.includes(txtName.toLowerCase());
      }
      rect.style("fill", function(d) {
        return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "yellow" : "transparent";
      })
      svgs2.style("fill", "blue")
})
```

This doesn't solve my problem though.  As mentioned before, when I apply the function to the line of code ie 
`svgs2.style("fill", function(d) {return meow(d.TooltipInfo) === true ? "black" : "transparent";  })`

I get the error code

> (error code: typeError: frat is undefined.)

`Frat`, the argument for the `meow` function, raises no errors when it is run in the previous line of code.  This is probably because `meow` is checking to see if `d.TooltipInfo` has a word that matches the input box.  I'm guessing that `d.TooltipInfo` is not actually associated to an svgs2 element and it is returning as `frat` as undefined. Confirmed this by writing a conditional that references `d.TooltipInfo` directly. (But how can it be the case that there is no data associated with the svgs2 element? The svgs2 comes from the dataset.)

Update #2: I thought I could get around the fact that d.TooltipInfo is not recognized by adding the data attribute to the svgs2 element, like so:

`svgs2.data(function(d) {return d.values;}).style("fill",function(d) {(d.values) === "advertising" ? "blue" : "transparent";  })`

no luck, alas

Update #3

Finally clued into the fact that the svg is an object that has text appended to it; whatever conditional formatting happens to the svg also happens to the text.  Thus, manipulating the height attribute of the svg to 0 will properly collapse it, and disappear the words - for example: `svgs2.attr("height",function(d) {return txtName === d.TooltipInfo ? "20" : "0";  })`

Now I just have to figure out how to make the svgs2 element explicitly attached to a line in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above code: remove the rects.  You can do the interactive aspects of the code by referencing the svgs.

Next,the information in the dataset associated with the svgs cannot be referenced via the standard `function(d) {return d.InsertDataNameHere}`.  Instead, they can be referenced using `this` as follows: `d3.select(this).datum().values[0].InsertDataNameHere`.

Here's the code.  I put 'bird' into one of the lines of your dataset.  A search for the term 'bird' should remove all but the relevant svg objects:

```js
var doc = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`TooltipInfo Category Function1 Function2 Retention
Lorem bird ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate Design Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Jack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Drooling Jack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Canine Files  Drooling Jack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum ADVERTISING At home Jack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum PROMOTIONS At home Jack 100
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Publications At homeio Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Public and Information Services At homeio Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Snack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Fundraising Optimal time of day Snack 7
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day Snack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Protective Measures Snack 5
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Protective Measures Pack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8`]));

d3.tsv(doc)
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      University: d.University,
      TooltipInfo: d.TooltipInfo,
      Category: d.Category,
      Function1: d.Function1,
      Function2: d.Function2,
      MaxRetentionRounded: d.MaxRetentionRounded,
      ModifiedRetention: d.ModifiedRetention
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, data) {
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0)

    var height = 150,
      width = 300;



    var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Function2;
      })
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Function1;
      })
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Category;
      })
      .entries(data);

    var height = 80,
      width = 150;


    var divs = d3.select(".container")
      .selectAll(null)
      .data(nest)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "innerdiv");

    divs.append("p")
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });



    var divs2 = divs.selectAll(null)
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr("class", "first")


    divs2.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'label1')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .style("font-size", "16px")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

    var svgs2 = divs2.selectAll(null)
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .enter()
      .append('svg')
      .attr("class", "second")
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return String(d.Category).length * 31
      })
      // .attr("width",200)
      .attr("height", 20);


    svgs2.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'label2')
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', 17)
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        // console.log(d3.select(this).datum().values[0].TooltipInfo)
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html(d3.select(this).datum().values[0].TooltipInfo)
          .style("left", function() {
            return d3.event.pageX > (window.innerWidth * .75) ? d3.event.pageX - 520 + "px" : d3.event.pageX + "px"
          })
          .style("bottom", function() {
            var clientrect = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect();
            return d3.event.pageY > (window.innerHeight - clientrect.height) ? window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY + "px" : window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY - clientrect.height + "px"
          })
        // .style(function() {return "bottom"}, window.innerHeight - d3.event.pageY+20 +"px")
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });
    var hat = function(event) {
      if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        //code to execute here
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    };

    d3.select("#txtName").on("keydown", function() {
      var txtName = d3.select("#txtName").node().value;
      var meow = function(frat) {
        return frat.includes(txtName.toLowerCase());
      }
      svgs2.attr("height", function(d) {
        return meow(d3.select(this).datum().values[0].TooltipInfo) === true ? "20" : "0";
      })
    })
  });
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 17px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: black;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.innerdiv {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
  flex: 1 1 1;
}

.innerdiv+.innerdiv {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
}

.legend {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}


/* div {width: auto; height: auto; } */

.first>*:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

div.first {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtName" name="txt-Name" style="width:600px; height:20px;" ></textarea>

<div class="container"></div>
```